# Firefox2 display: inline-block hack with position: relative not working

Tags: firefox, css

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to make this work in Firefox2 (and also IE6)?
http://collinatorstudios.com/ff2_test.html

I was able to emulate inline-block with the '-moz-inline-stack' hack, however it appears that it ignores position: relative, so elements with position absolute inside the inline-stack  container do not appear relative to where they should..  instead they are at the top right of the page in FF2...

I know FF2 is outdated and I probably shouldn't care, but I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this, and also I need it to work in IE6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I no longer have FF2 to test this for you, but I think the only way to make in work in that is to nest a div and apply position relative to the nested div so it would be inside you `li`

as for IE6 I think an alteration to your hacks should works for it too..

change:

```
 .item {
   list-style-type: none;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid teal;
   background: #00f;
   display: -moz-inline-stack; /* for FF2 */
   display: inline-block;
   /* <ie hacks> */
   zoom: 1;
   *display: inline;
   min-height: 50px;
   _height: 50px; /* for ie6 */
   /* </ie hacks> */
}
```

to:

```
 .item {
   list-style-type: none;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid teal;
   background: #00f;
   display: -moz-inline-stack; /* for FF2 */
   display: inline-block;
}

.item {/** IE Hacks **/
  display: inline !ie7; /* should work for 6 as well */
  _height: 50px; /* IE6 */
}
```

putting the `display:inline` rule in a separate ruleset means you don't need `zoom`, and it *should* work for both IE6 and 7.
I just moved the min-height hack to keep them together ;)  - as an aside I'm not sure why you've got min-height as you already have a height rule further up the stack and the 2nd height rule (which I removed) was just repeating, so perhaps you don't need the IE6 min-height hack anyway?